# How to figure out if $x,y,z$ are postive reals and $x(1+y)+y(1+z)+z(1+x)=6\sqrt{xyz}$ then $xyz=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please help me with this:
for $x,y,z$ real positive values prove if $x(1+y)+y(1+z)+z(1+x)=6\sqrt{xyz}$ then $xyz=1$
Thank you.

Comment: Need urgent answer, Thanks

Comment: What have you tried and where are you having trouble? You should add context (like answering the questions I asked) to you question.

Answer (score 6):

By AM-GM:

$$x + y + z + xy + yz + xz \geq 6 \sqrt[6]{x^3y^3z^3} = 6 \sqrt{xyz}$$

Equality when $x=y=z=xy=yz=xz$.

Solving $x=xy, y=yz, z=zx$ gives $x=y=z=1$, so $xyz = 1$.

Comment: -1 not given quickly enough.

Comment: @Woodface what?

Comment: It had to be *urgent* and you waited almost half an hour.

Comment: @Woodface I hope this is a joke. Can't expect someone to see every question as soon as it comes out..